# How to populate ListView and List onclick data?

Tags: android, listview

I have a database with Users and their data.
Then make ListView with their names.
How then set click listener to ListView assosiated with my List?
So when I click on List element strats new Activity with all User details, no only name?

```
package com.test.tabs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.test.tabs.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SelectFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        MySQLiteOpenHelper db = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(getActivity());
        List<User> users = db.getAllUsers();

        List<String> your_array_list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

            your_array_list2.add(users.get(i).getFirstName());
        }
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,your_array_list2);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement parcelable in your User class:

```
public class User implements Parcelable
{
....
}
```

Now you can attach/send your user to the next activity like so:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
         User user = adapter.getItem(position);
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b.putParcelable("user", user);

         Intent i = new Intent(context, OtherActivity.class);
         i.putExtra("bundle", b);
         startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

In the new activity call:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
User user = b.getParcelable("user");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView#setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener)`.

Comment: How to use LinkedList of Users in listener?

Comment: `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` has one method `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`. You can use `view` to get the text set to view that was clicked which will be user name for which you want to displayed detailed data. Or use `position` which is the position of the view in the adapter and get underlaying data for that view from adapter. Either way you will know for which user you should show detailed data.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @itsme86 Yes, it does. The detailed question was: 'How then set click listener to ListView assosiated with my List?'. The answer: 'Use ListView#setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener)'. Moreover I gave further instructions about what to do next.

Comment: @michal.z It would be helpful to include that information in your answer so people don't need to dig through the comments to find how to apply your solution in the given context. However, "Use X" is generally preferred as a comment to the question. You can reference the other answers to this question to see what a complete answer usually look like.

Comment: @itsme86 I believe sometimes it is better to give somebody a good hint than a complete solution. Give people a chance to think and improve not to copy&paste. Especially in such a simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use `Cursor Adpater` to populate listview from database. On item click event for each row, you can get corresponding cursor object, pass on some details to next activity, so it can fetch more user details and display to user.

You need to understand the basics first. Have a look at [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html) tutorial to have some idea.

Good Luck!